# Extract words from text file

Tags: python, awk

I am working with recursive neural networks and need to process my input text file (containing trees) to extract words.
The input file looks like :

> (3 (2 (2 The) (2 Rock)) (4 (3 (2 is) (4 (2 destined) (2 (2 (2 (2 (2 to) (2 (2 be) (2 (2 the) (2 (2 21st) (2 (2 (2 Century) (2 's)) (2 (3 new) (2 (2 ``) (2 Conan)))))))) (2 '')) (2 and)) (3 (2 that) (3 (2 he) (3 (2 's) (3 (2 going) (3 (2 to) (4 (3 (2 make) (3 (3 (2 a) (3 splash)) (2 (2 even) (3 greater)))) (2 (2 than) (2 (2 (2 (2 (1 (2 Arnold) (2 Schwarzenegger)) (2 ,)) (2 (2 Jean-Claud) (2 (2 Van) (2 Damme)))) (2 or)) (2 (2 Steven) (2 Segal))))))))))))) (2 .)))
>
> (4 (4 (4 (2 The) (4 (3 gorgeously) (3 (2 elaborate) (2 continuation)))) (2 (2 (2 of) (2 ``)) (2 (2 The) (2 (2 (2 Lord) (2 (2 of) (2 (2 the) (2 Rings)))) (2 (2 '') (2 trilogy)))))) (2 (3 (2 (2 is) (2 (2 so) (2 huge))) (2 (2 that) (3 (2 (2 (2 a) (2 column)) (2 (2 of) (2 words))) (2 (2 (2 (2 can) (1 not)) (3 adequately)) (2 (2 describe) (2 (3 (2 (2 co-writer/director) (2 (2 Peter) (3 (2 Jackson) (2 's)))) (3 (2 expanded) (2 vision))) (2 (2 of) (2 (2 (2 J.R.R.) (2 (2 Tolkien) (2 's))) (2 Middle-earth))))))))) (2 .)))

As an output I want the list of words in new text file as :

> The
>
> Rock
>
> is
>
> destined
>
> ...

(Ignore the spaces in between lines.)

I tried doing it in python but could not arrive at a solution. Also, I read that awk can be used for text processing but was unable to produce any working code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
with open('tree_file.txt') as f, open('word_list.txt', 'a') as f1:
   f1.write('\n'.join(set(re.findall("[a-zA-Z\-\.'/]+", f.read()))))
```

When running the code above on the text, the output is:

```
make
not
gorgeously
the
Conan
than
so
huge
and
co-writer/director
Peter
st
is
can
Schwarzenegger
expanded
even
trilogy
Middle-earth
Segal
continuation
column
vision
's
he
''
Damme
adequately
that
greater
Steven
Rock
Jackson
Rings
a
Tolkien
Van
be
words
going
to
new
Jean-Claud
or
elaborate
of
splash
Lord
The
Arnold
describe
destined
J.R.R.
Century
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing, some word contain ' and - like "he's" , "pre-emptive". How can I get those ?
And will this give me unique words in the output file ?

Comment: @user129129 Please see my recent edit. This solution will garner a unique listing.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're a saver.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex!

```
import re
my_string = # your string from above
pattern = r"\(\d\s+('?\w+)"
results = re.findall(pattern, my_string)
print(results)
# ['The',
#  'Rock',
#  'is',
#  'destined',
#  'to',
#  'be',
#  'the',
# ...
```

Note that [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return a list of matches, so if you want to print them all out in a single sentence, you can use:

```
' '.join(results)
```

or whatever other character you want to separate words with instead of a blank space.

Breaking the regular expression pattern down we have:

```
pattern = r"""
           \(           # match opening parenthesis
             \d         # match a number. If the numbers can be >9, use \d+
               \s+      # match one or more white space characters
                  (     # begin capturing group (only return stuff inside these parentheses)
                   '?   # match zero or one apostrophes (so we don't miss posessives)
                   \w+  # match one or more text characters
                  )     # end capture group
           """
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will re.findall give me unique instances ? If not, how can I get them ?

Comment: What do you mean "unique instances"? Like if something shows up more than once in a file you only want to read it once? In that case you can use `set(results)` if the order doesn't matter, or else `np.unique(results)` and add `import numpy as np` to the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And yes the order doesn't matter so will use set(results).

Answer (score 3):

For the record, we can choose what to throw away rather than what to keep. For example, we can split on parens, spaces and numbers. The reminder consists of words and punctuation. This might be handy for non-latin text and special characters.

```
import re

# split on parens, numbers and spaces
spl = re.compile("\(|\s|[0-9]|\)")
words = filter(None, spl.split(string_to_split))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.compile`:

```
import re
def getWords(text):
    return re.compile('[A-Za-z]').findall(text)

with open('input_file.txt') as f_in:
  with open('output_file.txt', 'a') as f_out:
    f_out.write('\n'.join(getWords(f_in.read())))
```